# Indoor Atlas: App build successfully but not run on Nexus 9 Tab(App has stopped working)

Tags: android, android-studio, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

Indoor Atlas app is build successfully but there is some error I found on logcat that I post here. Can anyone tell me How can I solved that error and make my app runnable?

```
03 10:25:48.893 5152-5168/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IdaSensorReadingManager
                                              Process: com.test.indoornavigation, PID: 5152
                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.test.indoornavigation/files/assetlib.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
                                                 at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:897)
                                                 at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1505)
                                                 at com.indooratlas._internal.db.a(SourceFile:211)
                                                 at com.indooratlas.algorithm.ClientProcessingManager.ensureNativeLibrary(SourceFile:174)
                                                 at com.indooratlas.algorithm.ClientProcessingManager.<init>(SourceFile:91)
                                                 at com.indooratlas.algorithm.ClientProcessingManager.getInstance(SourceFile:98)
                                                 at com.indooratlas._internal.an.f(SourceFile:485)
                                                 at com.indooratlas._internal.an.a(SourceFile:40)
                                                 at com.indooratlas._internal.an$a.handleMessage(SourceFile:774)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-03 10:25:48.956 587-1095/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 76) }
```

Comment: Looks like you may have both 32bit and 64bit native code deployed with your app. Which IndoorAtlas SDK version are you using and did you integrate it as JAR or AAR.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had a similar problem and I found figured out that is related to proguard rules for indoorAtlas, you need to put this in your proguard.pro file:

```
# Required by IndoorAtlas SDK
-keep public class com.indooratlas.algorithm.ClientProcessingManager { *; }
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

as shown here: https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/blob/master/Basic/proguard-rules.pro

I hope this help you!